# When my response has a very skewed distribution, is it called unbalanced or imbalanced?

Tags: unbalanced-classes

It is only a question of terminology. I am not a native speaker and was wondering, which term is used in what situation.

Comment: (1) in machine learning I'd use "class imbalance" (2) for more traditional statistics (maximum likelihood) would use "skewed" (3) would not use unbalanced often, if at all

Comment: Patrick "unbalanced" usually refers to the design, not the response. @charles It's not clear why you'd add "(maximum likelihood)" there  -- a statistician that *doesn't* maximize likelihood would be just as likely to say "skewed". (Also, you have me curious -- would you really call it "class imbalance" even if your response didn't have classes?)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the only proper term for a skewed distribution is "skewed". "Imbalanced" seems to be used for categorical variables, where skewness isn't useful.

Comment: Not the question, but I see no objection to talking about the skewness of an ordinal variable, although have some queasiness about measuring it!